# How can I combine a string with a date number in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, timestamp, applescript

```
set targetMessage to "Laptop logged in at" + timestamp
tell application "Messages"
    set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set targetBuddy to buddy targetBuddyPhone of targetService
    send targetMessage to targetBuddy
end tell
```

I receive an error message that says:

```
error "Can’t make \"Laptop logged in at\" into type number." number -1700 from "Laptop logged in at" to number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo (actually a relic from other languages). Your first line should use an & to combine strings.

```
set targetMessage to "Laptop logged in at " & timestamp
```

The error message makes sense. It thought you were trying to add the string to the number, so coercing it to a number failed.

Comment: This has worked. I thank you for the assistance. @jweaks.